# Routing MERN routing working on localhost but not on webserver

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes

My MERN based website is running, www.only4laugh.com, it's opening fine I can access other pages via clicking on funcards thumbnails, and it shows animation preview in this link (http://www.only4laugh.com/preview/0/jokes/world_record). But issue is when I copy paste this same link directly to another tab then it shows error "Cannot GET /preview/0/jokes/world_record", I am confused why it is working fine on my localhost, I need this to preview of cards with customized images. I am not getting why this is happening due to react route??? or maybe NGNIX based issue..... on node I am just serving app.get("/") to serving index.html.

Comment: in localhost, when you're on the route `/preview/0/jokes/world_record` try refreshing the page. are you getting a 404?

Comment: it's not showing any error on localhost... it's working fine on localhost,

Comment: also after a refresh on this route?

Comment: I mean No error at all on Local after refreshing route and open this page with directlink and putting dynamic id as well but donsn't know why showing error on AWS EC2 instance...

Comment: since `/preview/0/jokes/world_record` doesn't match the `"\"` route could you try changing your route from `app.get("\")` to `app.get("*")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways after trying lots of things, I got knows that the issue is while working on JS based clientside apps like React/Angular or others with router.... the Problem is when we navigate website through navlinks or other links provided in website then all requests are handled by client but problem occurs when we refresh browser or type some url manually on addessbar and the reason is when use did this then the request goes to serverside beside of clientside, and we did routing to clientside and server dosen't aware of that so after refreshing or entering some url on address bar makes app break, so the solution what I found is we need to do server side rendering and this is what I got, https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/

Anyways it's not our fault, keep try, and dn't worry about mistakes because it makes us human and failure keeps us grow..

Answer (score 0):

when using client side routing the `node` route should be `app.get("*")` which basically means **match all** incoming requests and always return the `index.html`.
the full URL will be kept and handled by the client's routing mechanism.
Another option is to declare a route for every option but I'm sure that this is not your intent.

Comment: I tried app.get("*") , into my server but instead to solution it performing another issue, my node server stops serving static files because it is giving all request to index.html, I strongly believe that it is NGINX routing issue.